# "It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs" Error

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-code, .net-core, runtime-error

I am trying to learn to program but I cant even use visual studio to do anything because when I type **"dotnet new console"** I keep getting the error:
**"It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
[https://aka.ms/dotnet-download"](https://aka.ms/dotnet-download%22)** I have already installed .NET Core SDKs and I have reinstalled it about 5 times, each trying something new like installing with vscode not open, with it open, rebooting my pc, checked forms and it does not work, This is my last option I can think of. Please help me fix this! I don't know if it would make a difference but I'm learning c#.

Comment: Yeah, save yourself the headache. Download Visual Studio 2022 (Community Edition), install it and it will install all the dependancies. During Setup choose all the components you want, Winform, ASP.Net, Python, Mobile, Node, etc.

Comment: Please include the output of `dotnet --info` in your question.

Comment: Run `where dotnet`, to make sure which utility you ran.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue when both versions 32-bit and 64-bit were installed.

This is how I fixed it:
Open command prompt and run the command "where dotnet". If the output should show the 64-bit version on top of the 32-bit version (if you see x86), do the following (in Windows 10):

1.search for edit the environment variable in start menu search bar and click "Edit the environment variables"

2. click "Environment Variables"
3. look for "Path" entry under "System variables" list
4. Select "Path" entry then click edit
5. Move up the 64-bit entry of dotnet (looks similar to this "c:\Program Files\dotnet" to be on top of the other 32-bit dotnet (looks similar to this "c:\Program Files x(86)\dotnet"
6. click Ok and close the window

Re-open the command prompt and re-run command "where dotnet" to make sure the the 64-bit version comes first in the output.